# Explain lookaround in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For putting `'` before `s` in all **Jeffs** I tested these two following little different regexes and I got different results by PERL as follows :

```
 perl -pe "s/(?<=\bJeff)(?=s)\b/'/g" myfile.txt
```

What is difference between `(?<=\bJeff)(?=s\b)` and `\b(?<=\Jeff)(?=s)\b` ?

I mean putting \b inside/outside lookaround.

Comment: You can write this more simply as `s/\bJeffs\nb/Jeff's/g`

Comment: A lookahead or a lookbehind assertion is also called a zero-width assertion. So you have to understand that these assertions (like `^` or `$`) don't consume characters and don't move the position of the regex engine. There are only tests at the current position.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of the regex engine maintaining a pointer in the string that marks its *current location*, pointing not at characters, but at locations between characters (or before the first character or after the last character). It then makes perfect sense that a positive lookahead immediately following a positive lookbehind matches a *zero-width* (i.e., empty) string at its current location in the string. It's not an anomaly; it's a powerful feature with many uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `\b` before the lookaround, the portion of the input matched by the lookaround is not skipped over when matching `\b`. This means it has to be matched immediately before `s`, not before `Jeff`. So you're matching a word boundary between `Jeff` and `s`, which isn't possible since they're both part of the same word. It's effectively equivalent to

```
(?<=Jeff)\b(?=s\b)
```